# When running a new uwp app as an update to an old one, is there a way to NOT delete the local state on install?

Tags: installation, uwp

I have associated my new app with the old one in the store, then when hitting Local Machine I get the message:

> The app ____ is already installed on this machine.
>
> if you continue with the current deployment , the existing app will be
> uninstalled and the apps current state will be deleted.

are you sure you want to continue?"

I need to keep the local state folder as that's where I have saved user data in the first version of the app, I don't want my users losing data.
Does any one know of a way to achieve this ?

Comment: This typically only happens when switching between Packaged / unpacked versions of an app, or using a different certificate. If the app is delivered via the Microsoft Store this shouldn't be a problem for the final update. If you're self signing and distributing the appx file manually, more complex.

Comment: Maybe you can copy data from `C:\Users\user\AppData\Packages\YourPackage` and paste it to newer package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not happen for actual users of your application who download it from the Store. The issue here is that when debugged, the app is signed with a local certificate as opposed to the Store-signed version. If you want to debug this "update" scenario, the easiest way to do so is:

- Checkout the older version of your app from Git
- Run it with debugger
- Add some data
- Close the app
- Checkout latest commit again
- Run app

Comment: Thank you, I have only released one app so far and sadly I lost the source code when I lost my PC, Its just a case i didnt what the users i have to lose any data they have input. so this has helped explain the workings for me.

Comment: As long as you associate the app with the Store under the reserved name, you should hopefully be able to update the app normally

Comment: I really hope it works, nothing irritates me more than an update eating my data. I will do a lot of test before I make it live just to be sure.